# Preinstall VSCode `code-server` and support both SSH and web?

Tags: vscode-remote

I'd like to build a container image which can be connected to via

- VSCode (desktop client) over SSH
- Browser (connect to VSCode Server)

I'd like to have a fully preinstalled container image, with no external dependencies, such that VSCode Server and extensions are preinstalled.

But it seems that the VSCode desktop client will install itself into `~/.vscode-server/bin/[some random uuid]`.

Can I make it reuse an existing installation, and its preinstalled extensions?

And is it possible to make it also serve web? I'm not interested in using Microsoft Tunnels.
Or do I have to use a third-party project like Coder or Gitpod for that?